# How do I build something like query inheritance with Doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a small website with Symfony2 and Doctrine2. There are blog posts, events and press releases. Each of these is so similar that I decided to use single table inheritance (STI) with a parent table called 'Node'.

Nodes have:

- a 'published' field, which is boolean
- a 'locale' field, which is a string and says 'this is only to be shown in this locale'. (The locale is passed in via the request).

By default, I only want to display published nodes that are from the current locale.

Obviously, I could create lots of queries in the repository that look something like:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('Event')
     ->where('Node.published = 1')
     ->where('Node.locale = :locale')
```

but this doesn't seem very DRY.

So how do I build a default query which other queries can 'inherit' from? This should include default Doctrine queries based on relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance is probably overkill.

Why not just create a little factory method that gives you a preconfigured queryBuilder?

```
class NodeRepository extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {

    public function getLocalizedNodeQueryBuilder($type,$locale){
        return $this->getQueryBuilder($type)
            ->where('Node.published = 1')
            ->where('Node.locale = :locale')
            ->setParameter('locale',$locale);
    }
}
```

You could do the same thing, and simply override getQueryBuilder if you're sure you always want your querybuilder configured that way.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build anything like that into your repository classes. If you set up single table inheritance with a "Discriminator Map" you'll end up with seperate classes (Entities). Doctrine will take care of filtering by your "node type" when it interacts with the DBAL.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

For example..

```
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"node" = "Node", "blogpost" = "Blogpost", "events" = "Events"})
 */
class Node
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Blogpost extends Node
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Events extends Node
{
    // ...
}


// get me all the blogposts
$blogposts = $em->getRepository('Blogpost')->findAll();

// get me all the events
$events = $em->getRepository('Events')->findAll();
```

This is especially beneficially as you'll be able to encapsulate your "Blogpost" logic into its own entity, rather than trying to represent it with its parent class "Node".

Comment: How do I add other filters onto it, like 'only show published nodes'?

Comment: as it extends the parent "Node" those values will still be available to query. So $em->getRepository('Events')->findAllBy(array('published' => 'yes')); should work.

Comment: Hmm, interesting - I could have a 'default properties' array and pass that to 'findAllBy()'. I can have getters and setters on that which exist in the Node Repository.

Comment: You could, but if you try to filter from the parent class you'll end up having to support it for all your child types, as well as adding additional filtering mechanisms for any additional child types you add. I think setting up the discriminator map and being able to encapsulate logic into child classes would be a neater implementation. Just realised who the author is, we met at PHP London a few months back. Small world :)