# Where to store extended Symfony entity logic

Tags: symfony

I've extended a class (FOSUserBundle), however while following symfony best practices of separating logic from doctrine entities, I've created a "logic" service that handles instantiation, object manipulation etc.

The problem occurs when I extend an entity, the type hinting, PHPdoc return object type etc of the service all refer to the super class and not the newly extended sub-class entity. Now I need to create new logic (and a service) to handle the new, extended entity.

I would not like to re-write this service / entity logic for each extended class (and I suspect this would be bad practice). It would be ideal to have a super service class that can be extended to handle the extended entities that are created.

**So my question is:** #1: what is the best practice for writing logic classes / services to handle extended entities?

My followup question is: #2: are there any good resources you can suggest on Symfony design for people like myself that are keen to understand symfony best practices? I've found the symfony website best practices a good primer, but lacking when it comes to intermediate / advanced best practices.

I'm looking forward to finding the answer to this one and appreciate any help you're able to provide :-)

Comment: I don't really get your question!? What is it that you want to extend? The service or the entities? But as far as I understand, my advice would be, don't *extend*. Use interfaces and injection.

Comment: Hi Yoshi, I'm extending the entity. However, the issue is when the entity is extended, the old service that handles the entity logic can no-longer be used because the service code refers to the entity superClass.

Comment: Why can it no longer be used? A type hint for the super class will accept the extending class. https://3v4l.org/pqfKZ

Comment: I had assumed it would throw an error so I've been trying to find answers for a large part of today. (rhetorical comment:) the service method must accept the sub-class as it exposes the same interface as the parent. Thanks for this, I'll try it out.

Comment: With respect to the second question, the Symfony 2 blog (http://symfony.com/blog/) publishes a weekly report containing links to interesting uses of Symfony.  Unfortunately, the term "best practices" is very misleading.  Intermediate/advanced solutions tend to be specific to a particular problem.  There is no one size fits all.  So get comfortable with Symfony 2's basic and then worry about advanced techniques.  And @Yoshi is correct: try to program against interfaces, not classes.

Comment: Thanks Cerad. As another note on extending entities, it appears that I now need to create new factory / instantiation logic and Doctrine find logic for each new entity I have created / extended from the superclass - and much of this instantiation and find code is identical to the superClass. And I imagine this would be the same for repository code; queries would be similar. If this is not the case please let me know! As much of this code is almost identical, I really feel like I'm missing an article (or 7) on Symfony object design that I should have read somewhere along the way...

Comment: I've found a similar SO question on repositories / Doctrine queries:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499115/how-do-i-build-something-like-query-inheritance-with-doctrine2

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by extending the service class that contains the extended entities logic and overriding two methods (the constructor and a newly created method that now houses only the "new className" line). This allows the service methods to be overridden to change the repository used (to the sub-class) so all other service methods using that entity's repository new refer to the extended entity's repo. Overriding the method containing the "new className()" with a "new extendedClassName()" also allows me to use factory methods.

Now the code looks great and I can re-use this stuff!

The subclassed-service that contains the sub-entity specific methods and class overiddes looks like this:

```
class PersonManager extends BasePersonManager
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->em           = $em;
        $this->repo         = $this->em->getRepository('TwenchaBundle:person');
        $this->dispatcher   = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function createNew () {
        return new person();
    }
}
```

While the base service class looks like this:

```
class BasePersonManager
{
    protected $em;
    protected $repo;
    protected $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->em           = $em;
        $this->repo         = $this->em->getRepository('PersonBundle:BasePerson');
        $this->dispatcher   = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function createNew () {
        return new BasePerson();
    }
...
```

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution that you are happy with.  Are you aware that you can extend the entity repository class itself and add your createNew statement to it?  Are you also aware that you can define repositories as services and perhaps get rid of the em->getRepository call?

Comment: Cheers Cerad, #1: moving the repo into a service and injecting it is an interesting idea, it would remove the need for the entity class to have knowledge / dependence on the EntityManager service (the protected $em can be removed also). Is there any other reason you might do this? As for the create() method #2: I' on the fence with this one; I thought the repo was designed more for queries than for instantiating objects/entities?